# Autosys condition with success of job or start_time

Tags: autosys, jil

I have an Autosys job that runs on a trigger called A, Success of other job B, But there will chances that every day job B won't run. In that case I need to trigger job A on specific time like 10:00 AM EST
I tried multiple solutions like lookback etc but job A is not getting triggering on time